# Managing SSH access and who has access

Tags: ssh, active-directory, ldap

I'm currently implementing AD and some of the users access external servers via SSH (not hosted within the AD) and I'm looking for a way to monitor who is accessing them and maybe limit them. As far as I see this can be done with LDAP, why I'm looking into LDAP is because it pairs nicely with AD as I've experienced in the past but never had to configure a scenario like this.
Anyone with perhaps such experience in this kind of scenario can share some info if this is a good idea or if something else could be used. I'm basically just looking to have a way to monitor (know when and who) the users who SSH to these external servers within the AD.

Comment: Why don’t you just use key authentication.  This way you control the generation of the key as the Administrator of the systems.